# Como gerar rótulos coloridos no comparison.cloud?

Tags: r, wordcloud

Abaixo segue um exemplo do código para gerar a **nuvem**:

```
comparison.cloud(tdm, random.order=FALSE,
                 colors = c("tomato", "wheat", "lightblue","lightgreen"))
```

As palavras são facilmente coloridas com o comando acima mas os rótulos continuam com fundo cinza.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você pode postar sua solução como uma reposta à sua própria pergunta. Dessa forma fica mais fácil identificar que o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Reforçando o que disso o Rodrigo,  o ideal é colocar sua resposta como resposta e não como edição da pergunta. Não tem problema nenhum - na verdade é recomendável - o próprio autor da pergunta compartilhar sua solução como resposta quando a encontra.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas!
Eu não sabia como colocar uma imagem na resposta então acabei  editando a pergunta. Mas agora coloquei no local correto!

Answer (score 1):

**Encontrei uma solução:**

Descobri que para efetuar tal ação faz-se necessário ir ao **código fonte**. 
Basta ir ao [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/) ou verificar através do próprio console.

Então altere uma linha adicionando o parâmetro de cores `col=colors[i]` conforme pode ser visto abaixo:

```
rect(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,x1+.5*wid,y1+.5*ht,col=colors[i], border="transparent")
```

E ao executar a função teremos as cores dos rótulos alteradas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aproveito para mostrar também como se altera a `cor da fonte`:

```
text(x1,y1,word,cex=title.size,col="white")
```